# Hashicorp Vault - AWS EKS vs EC2

Tags: amazon-eks, vault, aws-ec2, eks

Is it possible to install a Hashicorp Vault cluster to EC2 only or is EKS required and would there be a big advantage to one over the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vault runs on EC2 just fine. It is a a typical Kubernetes vs. Virtual machine descision. Vault has very little that's specific to it with that regard.

Running on virtual machine is generally more complex to setup because you'll have to provision storage, load-balancers, etc. But if you don't already have a EKS cluster ready and Kubernetes expertise it will be easier to deploy Vault on EC2.

Also, running on a virtual machine makes it easier to [keep mlock enabled](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/configuration#disable_mlock) and [hook to an HSM](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/configuration/seal/pkcs11) (Vault Enterprise only).